# How can I get Api data in a Component and use the data I get in another?

Tags: reactjs

This is where I would like to "stock" my API data.
It's a component named api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

function Api() {

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    };
    
    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

}

export default Api
```

Here is where I would like to use the data from it and build my component.
It's a component named component.js and it's located inside a folder named components.

```
import Api from "../api";

function Component() {
  
  return (
    <div>

    </div>

  )
}

export default Component
```

Answer (score 2):

If your objective with the API component is to only have helper functions to retrieve data from certain endpoints, the best thing would be to construct a helper JS file with these functions, and call these functions from the components that need the data. If you need to store this data in a state accessible by several components, you might want to look at tools like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).